# Drop down menu behind embedded PDF

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, pdf

I have the following code to create a drop down menu. However, on any page that has an embedded PDF the drop down appears behind the PDF.  It only seems to happen in IE.  Is there any fix?

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Website</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>

      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option 1
            <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option 2
            <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here's my code for the embedded PDF also:

```
<object data="file.pdf" id="myDoc" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="1000px">
  alt : <a href="folder/file.pdf">HowToCopyADisc.pdf</a>
</object>
```